# button disappeared after configuration laravel

Tags: laravel, radio-button

hello my radiobutton disappeared after a laravel configuration they are used to modify user roles they worked for a moment and then disappeared

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Modifier <strong> {{ $user->name }}</strong></div>


                <div class="card-body">
                <form action="{{ route('admin.user.update', $user) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('PATCH')
                @foreach ($roles as $role)
                <div class="form-group form-check">


                @foreach ($user->roles as $userRole)
                @if ($userRole->id == $role->id)
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="roles[]" value="{{ $userRole }}" checked>
                @else
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="roles[]" value="{{ $userRole }}">

                @endif
                @endforeach 


                <label for="{{ $role->id }}" class="form-check-label">{{ $role->name }}</label>

                </div>
                @endforeach

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier les roles</button>  
                </form>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem, could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2020-07-4-1581584249-issou.png here is a picture of my missing radiobutton

Comment: okay, I understand now. It looks like a css problem try removing the class="form-check-input" if then it appears there's some css acting over it

Comment: @kamil you're setting checkboxes values to an object  `value="{{ $userRole }}"` , it must be a number or string like (0,1, "val")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` with key and value defined:

The `contains()` method determines whether the collection contains a given item:

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
   <div class="form-group form-check">

       <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="roles[]" value="{{ $role->id }}" {{ $user->roles->contains('id', $role->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} >
       <label for="{{ $role->id }}" class="form-check-label">{{ $role->name }}</label>

  </div>
@endforeach
```